# Programmable Display Solution

Tags: operating-system, osx-mavericks

I have a question, How do you programmatically change the Display Settings using a Text Editor or a Hex Editor in Mac? I turned on the Mirror Display on my System Preferences, because I cant boot up the other monitor due to the settings I recently imposed. :) I will up vote any properly estimated solution. Thanks!